# Sublime Text not working with Python hidden pyc file

Tags: python, sublimetext2

On some python files `Ctrl+b` works. On files outside certain dir, it fails. Previously, it was working everywhere. I recently pip installed 
some twitter modules.

trace:

```
[0, 0, 9, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 568, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 550, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 283, in _init_posix
    _parse_makefile(makefile, vars)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 196, in _parse_makefile
    _variable_rx = re.compile("([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*(.*)")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

Comment: Did you name a file "re.py"?

Comment: No, I didnt, then again I just installed pip install twiiter, tweepy, python-twitter, they may have...Is there a fix, On linux, re-installed python from repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future: I didnt name a file re.py recently, But month ago, And then combined the two dir were combined and one had a hidden re.pyc file in the long list of files. Deleted the re.pyc, problem solved.